# jQuery append html with scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help with jQuery.

When i'm trying to get html with embded js page content via $.get, it's works good. But when i'm trying to append it to some div, all scripts are removing.

In a console its look fine when i'm doing smthing like this

```
$('.my_div').html() + '<script>alert("text")</script>'
```

but when i'm doing

```
 $('.my_div').html($('.my_div').html() + '<script>alert("text")</script>')
```

script is running and removing

How can i append html+js code to div without running and removing?

Thanks!

UPD:

My example :

index.html

...

```
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="a1">
        <p>text</p>
        <script>alert('example')</script>
    </div>
    <div class="a1">
        <p>text</p>
        <script>alert('example')</script>
    </div>
    <div class="a1">
        <p>text</p>
        <script>alert('example')</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

```
<script>

$.get('get_news.php',function(response){

    $('.masonry').append(response);

});
</script>
```

...

get_news.php

```
    <div class="b1">
        <p>text</p>
        <script>alert('example1')</script>
    </div>
    <div class="b1">
        <p>text</p>
        <script>alert('example1')</script>
    </div>
    <div class="b1">
        <p>text</p>
        <script>alert('example1')</script>
    </div>
```

...

And i'm going to get

```
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="a1">
        <p>text</p>
        <script>alert('example')</script>
    </div>
    <div class="a1">
        <p>text</p>
        <script>alert('example')</script>
    </div>
    <div class="a1">
        <p>text</p>
        <script>alert('example')</script>
    </div>

    <div class="b1">
        <p>text</p>
        <script>alert('example1')</script>
    </div>
    <div class="b1">
        <p>text</p>
        <script>alert('example1')</script>
    </div>
    <div class="b1">
        <p>text</p>
        <script>alert('example1')</script>
    </div>

</div>
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Have you tried adding the script as text()?

Comment: What do you mean by "running and removing?"  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @xylar yes, without success =(

Comment: @ExplosionPills I mean in this case **$('.my_div').html($('.my_div').html() + '<script>alert("text")</script>')** i get alert in browser and no one word about **<script>alert("text")</script>** in code =(

Answer (score 1):

That's the default behavior of `.html()` - it will strip out scripts and `eval` them while appending content to the DOM. jQuery even provides [`$.parseHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) which defaults to stripping out scripts without evaluating them to prevent against XSS.

If you're already executing a script in the page, the vast majority of the time you can just put your code in the same script. But if you **really** want/need to append a new script to the page, you can do it through [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('.my_div').append($('<script>', { text: 'alert("foo");' }));
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4xUvB/)

Comment: no success with this `$('.my_div').append($('<script>', { text: 'alert("foo");' }));` in result i catch just **foo** but i need to take **<script>alert('foo')</script>**

Comment: Inspect the fiddle, it clearly has the `script` tag appended to the DOM. Though, this sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - update the question to show us what's the issue you're trying to solve with this and we'll find a better way around.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the `keepScripts` parameter for [`parseHTML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use append if you don't want to remove the original content. As for stop the script tag from executing, one way is to change to script type to `"text/html"` or use html escape function.

http://jsfiddle.net/R5xad/